# NodeJs Async Function is not waiting for promise values to return

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

Hello dear developers,

I’m struggling since days with a function that’s creating a doc in MongoDb but have to create the linked documents at the same time. So I have documents that have supports which have roles. My code is actually working and creating everything I need, but I can’t get why it’s returning an empty value, without waiting for the process to complete. But when I check in the Db everything is working it’s just that he doesn’t wait to return. Any idea of why ? I probable have misunderstood the specificities of async functions but I can’t find any solution so far.

Thank you for your precious help, and there’s my code :

```
const createSupportDependencies = async (req, doc) => {
  req.body.supports.map(async (support, index) => {
    support.doc = doc.id
    if (support.role && support.role.slug) {
      const newRole = await Role.create(support.role)
      support.role = newRole.id
     }
    const newSupport = await Support.create(support)
    doc.supports.push(newSupport.id)
    if (index === req.body.supports.length - 1) {
      doc.save()
      return doc 
    }
  })    
}

export const createDoc = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const doc = new Doc(req.body.doc)    
      const docWithSupports = req.body.supports ? await createSupportDependencies(req, doc) : doc.save()
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Doc has been successfully created.",
        data: docWithSupports
      }) 
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: err.message
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two things here.

##### 1. The return value of `Array.map` callback is not a direct return of top-level function `createSupportDependencies`.

You don't need to check indexes and then decide if you should return! You can just return outside of the map!

```js
const createSupportDependencies = async (req, doc) => {
  req.body.supports.map(async support => {
    support.doc = doc.id;
    if (support.role && support.role.slug) {
      const newRole = await Role.create(support.role);
      support.role = newRole.id;
    }
    const newSupport = await Support.create(support);
    doc.supports.push(newSupport.id);
  });
  return doc.save();
};
```

Since you are using await inside of the map callback for creating new `Role` and `Support` this ensures that `Role` and `Support` is getting created already.

##### 2. you need to wait until the doc gets saved to the database or you can return the promise that can be awaited in parent function.

Top-level `await` inside `createDoc` function does not ensures that the document save is completed!

A. Returning a promise

```js
return doc.save()
```

B. Returning the result after ensuring the save is completed

```js
// Here you need to await until document get's saved
await doc.save();
return doc;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the creation is still working but that doesn’t change anything to my problem unfortunately. As before everything is created and saved in db but the function is returning before, so it’s returning an empty value

Comment: Hey @NilsLopez, I've modified my answer. After looking closely I found another problem and am sorry for not looking closely at first. cheers!

Comment: Thanks, your answer actually seems really logical to me. But believe it or not there’s still a problem somewhere cause it’s still returning the doc before adding the supports. Sorry to bother you again and I really appreciate the time you’re giving me.

Comment: What ODM you are using? What does `new Doc()` returns